# To enable datadog extension, will i have to disable Datadog forwarder?

Tags: aws-lambda, datadog

I have been trying to enable Datadog extension using,
datadog-ci lambda instrument -f  -f <another_functionname> -r <aws_region> -v 80 -e 48
which has been provided in Datadog Docs, https://docs.datadoghq.com/serverless/installation/python/?tab=datadogcli

All works well, the lambda get's instrumented but i see few traces getting dropped.

Is there a need to disable the lambda Forwarder before enabling the extension?